# svchost.exe usosvc is taking up excessive amounts of memory

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

The `Update Orchestrator Service` service is taking up 7.6GB of memory.  I tried to stop it using `net stop usosvc` from an administrator command prompt, but it refused to die.  I then killed it.  I could keep the service off, but that will keep Windows from updating.

I am wondering if anyone else is having this issue, and if there is a fix out there.  I can't have this eating up so much memory.  I'm running Windows 10 Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.371)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related - [Windows Update stuck](https://superuser.com/q/1582778).

Answer (score 1):

People who have faced [similar circumstances](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/89109-high-cpu-ram-usage-windows-update.html) were successful when they utilized Shawn Brink's batch file to reset the Windows Update components.

You can paste the following code into Notepad and save it as a `.bat` file:

```
@echo off

:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: Created on: October 1st 2015
:: Updated on: February 12th 2018
:: Tutorial: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24742-reset-windows-update-windows-10-a.html


:: Checking and Stopping the Windows Update services
set b=0

:bits
set /a b=%b%+1
if %b% equ 3 (
   goto end1
) 
net stop bits
echo Checking the bits service status.
sc query bits | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto bits 
) 
goto loop2

:end1
cls
echo.
echo Cannot reset Windows Update since "Background Intelligent Transfer Service" (bits) service failed to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start


:loop2
set w=0

:wuauserv
set /a w=%w%+1
if %w% equ 3 (
   goto end2
) 
net stop wuauserv
echo Checking the wuauserv service status.
sc query wuauserv | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto wuauserv 
) 
goto loop3

:end2
cls
echo.
echo Cannot reset Windows Update since "Windows Update" (wuauserv) service failed to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start



:loop3
set app=0

:appidsvc
set /a app=%app%+1
if %app% equ 3 (
   goto end3
) 
net stop appidsvc
echo Checking the appidsvc service status.
sc query appidsvc | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto appidsvc 
) 
goto loop4

:end3
cls
echo.
echo Cannot reset Windows Update since "Application Identity" (appidsvc) service failed to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start


:loop4
set c=0

:cryptsvc
set /a c=%c%+1
if %c% equ 3 (
   goto end4
) 
net stop cryptsvc
echo Checking the cryptsvc service status.
sc query cryptsvc | findstr /I /C:"STOPPED" 
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( 
    goto cryptsvc 
) 
goto Reset

:end4
cls
echo.
echo Cannot reset Windows Update since "Cryptographic Services" (cryptsvc) service failed to stop.
echo.
pause
goto Start


:Reset
Ipconfig /flushdns
del /s /q /f "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Downloader\qmgr*.dat" 
del /s /q /f "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Network\Downloader\qmgr*.dat"
del /s /q /f "%SYSTEMROOT%\Logs\WindowsUpdate\*"


if exist "%SYSTEMROOT%\winsxs\pending.xml.bak" del /s /q /f "%SYSTEMROOT%\winsxs\pending.xml.bak" 
if exist "%SYSTEMROOT%\winsxs\pending.xml" ( 
    takeown /f "%SYSTEMROOT%\winsxs\pending.xml" 
    attrib -r -s -h /s /d "%SYSTEMROOT%\winsxs\pending.xml" 
    ren "%SYSTEMROOT%\winsxs\pending.xml" pending.xml.bak 
) 

if exist "%SYSTEMROOT%\SoftwareDistribution.bak" rmdir /s /q "%SYSTEMROOT%\SoftwareDistribution.bak"
if exist "%SYSTEMROOT%\SoftwareDistribution" ( 
    attrib -r -s -h /s /d "%SYSTEMROOT%\SoftwareDistribution" 
    ren "%SYSTEMROOT%\SoftwareDistribution" SoftwareDistribution.bak 
) 

if exist "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\Catroot2.bak" rmdir /s /q "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\Catroot2.bak" 
if exist "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\Catroot2" ( 
    attrib -r -s -h /s /d "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\Catroot2" 
    ren "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\Catroot2" Catroot2.bak 
) 


:: Reset Windows Update policies
reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate" /f
reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate" /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate" /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate" /f
gpupdate /force


:: Reset the BITS service and the Windows Update service to the default security descriptor
sc.exe sdset bits D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)

sc.exe sdset wuauserv D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)

:: Reregister the BITS files and the Windows Update files
cd /d %windir%\system32
regsvr32.exe /s atl.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s urlmon.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s mshtml.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s shdocvw.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s browseui.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s jscript.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s vbscript.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s scrrun.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s msxml.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s msxml3.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s msxml6.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s actxprxy.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s softpub.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wintrust.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s dssenh.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s rsaenh.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s gpkcsp.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s sccbase.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s slbcsp.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s cryptdlg.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s oleaut32.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s ole32.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s shell32.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s initpki.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wuapi.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wuaueng.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wuaueng1.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wucltui.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wups.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wups2.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wuweb.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s qmgr.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s qmgrprxy.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wucltux.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s muweb.dll 
regsvr32.exe /s wuwebv.dll
regsvr32.exe /s wudriver.dll
netsh winsock reset
netsh winsock reset proxy

:: Set the startup type as automatic
sc config wuauserv start= auto
sc config bits start= auto 
sc config DcomLaunch start= auto 

:Start
net start bits
net start wuauserv
net start appidsvc
net start cryptsvc
```

You can also download the batch file from the original source below.  Once you have it, execute it in the following manner:

> 1. Download the batch file [Reset_Reregister_Windows_Update_Components.bat](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/176819d1518453404-reset-windows-update-windows-10-a-reset_reregister_windows_update_components.bat)
> 2. Save the .bat file to your desktop.
> 3. [Unblock](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5357-unblock-file-window-10-a.html)
>      the .bat file.
> 4. Right-click the .bat file and select **Run as administrator**.
> 5. If prompted by [UAC](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3577-change-user-account-control-uac-settings-windows-10-a.html),
>      click on **Yes** to approve.
> 6. When finished, [restart the computer](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7370-restart-computer-windows-10-a.html)
>      to apply. **It is important to restart the computer right after
>      running the .bat file**.

(Source: [How to Reset Windows Update in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24742-reset-windows-update-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: Thanks, I've ran the batch file already, but prolly won't know for sure if it fixed the issue till next Monday.

Comment: No problem, @Adrian.  You always know where to find us!

Comment: Seems that it mitigated the issue, but it still exists.  Just took longer. :(

Comment: @Adrian, that's unfortunate.  It sounds like this occurs every time there are new Windows Updates to install.  Faced with the same situation, I would try running the `sfc /scannow` command to help ensure that your operating system file integrity remains intact:  [How to Repair Corrupted Windows System Files with the SFC and DISM Commands](https://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/)