# Windows 11 Reordering Partitions

Tags: partitioning, windows-update

After cloning my old M.2 all Windows cumulative updates are failing. When researching possible reasons I discovered my partitions are not in recommended order. Instead of EFI>System Reserved>Primary my partitions are ordered System Reserved>EFI>Primary.

[image: Partition Order]

According to [this article](http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/) and discussions found at answers.microsoft.com the correct order is:

[image: Partition Order]

All of my partitions do have a correct GUID assigned.

Could this be the reason why my Windows Updates are failing and if so is it possible to reorder the System and Reserved partitions without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Unlikely. Try to fix Windows Update with the steps from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1589956/8672) that apply to your case.

Comment: If you are booting and IN THE OS, it is extremely unlikely that this is the cause of your woes.  If you want to chase a red herring.. proceed.  I myself would focus elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing this by doing an in place upgrade with the latest July 2022 ISO image I downloaded from MSDN. Windows update now works fine and I have the latest version.